# Install methods via terminal not responding for typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

I cannot get anything to install via my terminal. In this case I was trying to install typescript and these commands I have already tried based on other posts.

I have tried using

```
npm install <package> 
npm i <package>
npm install -g <package>
```

and then I have used

```
npm cache clean
npm cache clean -force
npm cache clean --force
```

I also tried

```
yarn install <package>
```

I cannot use npm and I even tried

```
npm install -g npm
```

It's already install on my computer so it was just a suggestion I found that didn't do much

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ node -v
v14.15.4
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ npm -v
6.14.10
```

I have also used all forms with sudo and nothing seems to stick. I have read multiple pages and none of the solutions has helped me. Here is the general error message I get in my terminal.

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ npm install -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T20_24_30_961Z-debug.log
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ npm install -g npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T20_25_05_439Z-debug.log
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ npm install -g typescript
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T20_26_13_226Z-debug.log
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ npm i -g node
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-01-14T20_26_27_968Z-debug.log
```

I uninstalled npm and reinstalled but I still get errors. Even when I attempt to install it globally this is what I get.

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro:Typescript apple$ npm install -g typescript
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2021-01-25T19_53_29_238Z-debug.log
Apples-MacBook-Pro:Typescript apple$ sudo npm install -g typescript
Password:

added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 844ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
Apples-MacBook-Pro:Typescript apple$
```

Comment: I uninstalled npm and reinstalled but I still get errors. Even when I attempt to install it globally this is what I get.

Comment: Use this command:
npm install typescript --save-dev